# Bootstrap Validation - Turning it off

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1 and Telerik's Kendo UI.

I wish to only use the Kendo validation. How do I disable completely Bootstrap validation?

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript code for Destroy Plugin `$(form).data('formValidation').destroy()`. hope this help you